# How would the fresco in the Hall of 500 be repaired after Vayentha fell through it?

Tags: plot-explanation, inferno

When Robert Langdon and Sienna Brooks are above the Hall of 500, Sienna falls down to the floor. She is unhurt, and shortly later, Vayentha comes in and attempts to kill Langdon. Sienna pulls Vayentha down, and she (Vayentha) falls straight through the floor into the Hall of 500. It is very clear that the fresco is very, very badly damaged. How would it ever be repaired? Would Langdon ever let Sienna do such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

> **Would Langdon ever let Sienna do such a thing?**

In matter of life and death he would let her do because for him any piece of art is less valuable than life (also true in real life ).

Following instances support my above statement.

1. In Da Vinci Code Langdon throw away the Cryptex for saving Sophie Neveu's life.
2. In Angels and Demons he tore apart a page from Newton's notebook because there was less time.
3. Also in Angels and Demons he tried to break glass wall of Vatican's library when he was suffocated inside.

A piece of art will not matter when someone is trying to shoot you. Your flight and fight response will always be in favor of saving life first.

> **How would it ever be repaired?**

**[Conservation and restoration of paintings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_and_restoration_of_paintings)**

> The conservation and restoration of paintings is carried out by professional painting conservators. Paintings cover a wide range of various mediums, materials, and their supports (i.e.- The painted surface made from fabric, paper, wood panel, fabricated board, or other).

Comment: I get the second part, but don't you think the first part should be stressed more here? How would it be repaired?

Comment: @AravindSuresh: If you are thinking it was a real ceiling it wasn't. It's CGI.

Comment: Of course it's CGI.

Comment: @AravindSuresh: Check my modified answer. I have linked how conservation and restoration of art materials is done.